# Column Sum in SQL

Tags: sql

I have the below query:

```
select
 a.jobid
,a.jobnavn
,a.jobstart
,a.ExpTypeDescr
,b.Quote
,b.Expense
,b.Invoiced
,b.Actual

from job a
             INNER JOIN JobAdjustmentDetails AS b ON a.jobid = b.jobid

where a.jobid = '704289'
```

That generates a table like below:

[image]

I would like to sum the columns so that i get one line for each of the types in the column 'ExpTypeDescr' so it looks like below?

[image]

Can anyone advise the simplest way to do this?

I was trying `sum(distinct)` on each column holding a value but it wasn't the result I was hoping for.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use a group by:

```
SELECT a.jobid
    ,a.jobnavn
    ,a.jobstart
    ,a.ExpTypeDescr
    ,sum(b.Quote) AS Quote
    ,sum(b.Expense) AS Expense
    ,sum(b.Invoiced) AS Invoiced
    ,sum(b.Actual) AS Actual
FROM job a
INNER JOIN JobAdjustmentDetails AS b ON a.jobid = b.jobid
WHERE a.jobid = '704289'
GROUP BY a.jobid
    ,a.jobnavn
    ,a.jobstart
    ,a.ExpTypeDescr
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use group by:

```
select
 a.jobid
,a.jobnavn
,a.jobstart
,a.ExpTypeDescr
, sum(b.Quote)
,sum(b.Expense)
,sum(b.Invoiced)
,sum(b.Actual)

from job a
    INNER JOIN JobAdjustmentDetails AS b ON a.jobid = b.jobid

where a.jobid = '704289'  
group by a.jobid, a.jobnavn, a.jobstart, a.ExpTypeDescr
```